# Does Azure storage allow path traversal?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, path-traversal

Security-wise, if I receive parts of the path from the user, do I need to sanitize them?

Oversimplified example (in Python):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<mypassword>")
container = client.get_container("mycontainer")
container.upload_blob(f"path/{input()}", b"data")
```

Can `input()` contain `../` and thus cause a path traversal attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, azure storage does not allow path traversal.

When it detects the path has `../`, it will throw an authentication error.

In short, if the path looks like this `path/path2/../aa.txt`, in client side, this path will be used to generate a token; in server side, it will automatically remove the `../` from the path, then use the new path(which does not contain `../`) to generate a token. Thus the client side token does not match the server side token when authentication. Then an error occurs.